# How do you make VBA run on multiple cells?

Tags: excel, vba

I am very new to VBA but pretty good at formulas.  I am working on a time stamp issue.  I have the code written so that if I choose from a validation list in E3 it will give me a time stamp in F3.  I want this to be true of all cells in the E column starting with E3.  I will have between 500 and 15000 records (rows).  The code I am using is pasted below.  Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Target.Column = 5 And Target.Row = 3 Then
    If Target.Value = "" Then
      Cells(3, 6).Value = ""
    Else
      Cells(3, 6).Value = Format(Now, "mm/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss")
    End If
  End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

How's this?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Target.Column = 5 And Target.Row >= 3 Then
  i = Target.Row
    If Target.Value = "" Then
  Cells(i, 6).Value = ""
Else
  Cells(i, 6).Value = Format(Now, "mm/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss")
End If
 End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Joe, that is awesome, I figured it would not take an expert too long to figure it out.  THANKS!!!

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way to do this is to select the entire range a set the value once using an array. This is done with the `.Value` property of a `Range` when it contains multiple cells.

```
Private Sub SetDate(ByVal Target As Range, Optional bybal RowCount as Long = 0)
    Dim i as Long
    ' Check if row count needs to be found
    If RowCount = 0 Then
        'Count non-empty rows from target down
        RowCount = Target.Worksheet.Range(Target, Target.End(xlDown).Rows.Count
    End If
    ' Target entire range of cells that are going to be affected
    Set Target = Target.Resize(RowCount, 6)
    Dim vals() as Variant 
    ' Read values from worksheet
    vals = Target.Values        
    ' Make changes in memory here
    For i=1 to RowCount
        if IsEmpty(vals(i,1)) Then
            vals(i, 6) = vbNullString
        Else
            vals(i, 6) = Format(Now, "mm/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss")
        End If
    Next i
    ' Write values into worksheet
    Target.Value = vals
End Sub
```